# Menu delay for QToolBar

Tags: qt

I have a menu on a QToolBar by making a QAction and adding a QMenu to it. How can I remove the delay before the menu appears when you click on the icon ?

```
QToolBar *myToolBar = new QToolBar(this);
QAction *myAction = new QAction(helloIcon, tr("Hello"), this);
myToolBar->addAction(myAction);

helloMenu = new QMenu(this);
QAction *actionWorld = helloMenu->addAction(tr("World"));
QAction *actionUniverse = helloMenu->addAction(tr("Universe"));
myAction->setMenu(helloMenu);
```

Comment: The documentation for QToolButton says that the default popupDelay is 600ms and I think this is the delay I am experiencing. But I'm not using tool buttons and there is no way to access the equivalent QToolButton for an action, is there ?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is to insert a QToolButton yourself in the toolbar instead of a QAction. QToolButton class has a popupMode property where you can set the desired mode (delayed, instantPopup, menu).

Here is a working example:

```
QToolBar *myToolBar = new QToolBar(this);
QToolButton *myButton = new QToolButton();

QMenu *helloMenu = new QMenu(this);
QAction *actionWorld = helloMenu->addAction(tr("World"));
QAction *actionUniverse = helloMenu->addAction(tr("Universe"));

//set popup mode to InstantPopup so there will be no delay
myButton->setPopupMode(QToolButton::InstantPopup);
myButton->setMenu(helloMenu);
myButton->setIcon(helloIcon);
myButton->setText(tr("Hello"));

myToolBar->addWidget(myButton);
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to adjust the delayed menu time? i think the default is a bit to slow

Answer (score 1):

This should help, I don't know if it's the best solution though:

```
#ifdef OS_WIN
#include <QWindowsStyle>

class FixPopupDelayWinStyle : public QWindowsStyle
{
public:
    int styleHint(StyleHint hint, const QStyleOption* opt = 0, const QWidget* widget = 0, QStyleHintReturn* returnData = 0 ) const
    {
        if (hint == QStyle::SH_ToolButton_PopupDelay)
            return 0;
        return QWindowsStyle::styleHint(hint, opt, widget, returnData);
    }
};
#endif


#ifdef OS_WIN
_toolBar_contains_action_with_Menu->setStyle(new FixPopupDelayWinStyle);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of implementing it so that there is no delay when opening the menu:

main.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QToolBar>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
    void on_myAction();
private:
    QMenu * helloMenu;
    QToolBar *myToolBar;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QAction>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QWidget>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    myToolBar = new QToolBar(this);
    QAction *myAction = new QAction(tr("Hello"), this);
    myToolBar->addAction(myAction);

    helloMenu = new QMenu(this);
    QAction *actionWorld = helloMenu->addAction(tr("World"));
    QAction *actionUniverse = helloMenu->addAction(tr("Universe"));

    myAction->setMenu(helloMenu);

    QObject::connect(myAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(on_myAction()));
}

void Widget::on_myAction()
{
    helloMenu->popup(myToolBar->mapToGlobal(myToolBar->geometry().bottomLeft()));
}
```

---

### Notes on Using PopUp

When looking at the documentation for [`QMenu::popUp()`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qmenu.html#popup), it refers
to setting the sizeHint before checking the geometry.

> When positioning a menu with exec() or popup(), bear in mind that you
>   cannot rely on the menu's current size(). For performance reasons, the
>   menu adapts its size only when necessary, so in many cases, the size
>   before and after the show is different. Instead, use sizeHint() which
>   calculates the proper size depending on the menu's current contents.

So if you had a very complex menu this might help:

You should try calculating the `sizeHint` before it is shown; probably shortly after your code above.  This may reduce the time to show the menu later.

```
helloMenu->sizeHint();

// or you can try
qDebug() << helloMenu->sizeHint();
```

If that doesn't seem to help, you can also try calling `adjustSize()` on the `QMenu` to see if it will perform any calculations earlier.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That doesn't help; I don't think it is a slowdown due to processing, rather a programmed delay before showing the menu.

Comment: There may be a way to change the "pop up mode"... http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qtoolbutton.html#ToolButtonPopupMode-enum